# setting select2 options has duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have two dropdowns. one is a category dropdown and one is a select2 item dropdown. the behavior should be that if i select a category in the first dropdown, all items under that category will be displayed in the (select2) second dropdown. i can do this already but the problem is, each item displayed has a duplicate. what could i do to prevent this from having duplicates? here's my code:

in the category dropdown:

```
$(".field8").change(function () {
var catVal = $('.field8 option:selected').text();
array_items_selected = [];
$('.field1').val("");
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < array_items.length; ctr++) 
{
    if (array_items[ctr]['objCat'] == catVal)
    {
        if (array_items[ctr]['objCat'] != "NULL")
        {
            $('.field1 option[value="'+ array_items[ctr]['objName']+'"]').prop("selected", true).trigger('change');            


        }
    }
}
```

in setting the options for the select2 dropdown:

```
$.each(data, function (i, obj) {
var div_data = "<option value=\'"+ obj.Name + "\'>" + obj.Name + "</option>";
$(div_data).appendTo('.field1');
var objName = obj.Name;
var objCat = obj.Category;
array_items.push({ objCat, objName });
```

Comment: Is the second drop down multiple by any chance?

Comment: yes the second dropdown is multiple